# Environment variable change didn't work

Tags: windows, windows-7, path, environment-variables

I am building an installer for a piece of software that requires a third-party executable to be in the path in order to run. In other words, my software calls `3rdparty.exe` with a system call.

I ran the 3rd party installer and then ran my software, but my software did not find `3rdparty.exe` because the path environment variable hadn't been changed. I confirmed this by running `set > file.txt` at a **brand new** command line and the new addition to the path was not there. Yes, I started the new command line after the 3rd party software completed--minutes after.... so yes, the environment variables should have been populated.

Now here's the weird part. I went to the "Environment Variables" dialog box to edit the System path, and guess what, the new path was already there, tacked on to the end of the old one.

So here's the facts I'm left with:

- The third-party installer makes a change to the System path
  environment variable, adding `C:\program files\blah\...` to the end of
  the path.
- This shows up immediately in "Environment Variables" dialog box.
- This **did not** show up without a reboot in any new cmd.exe shell I
  started. Yes, I tried it multiple times.

I have never seen this behavior before. Can someone please explain what is going on here? I have operated for years under the presumption that once the environment variable has been set, any new process would get a copy of the full, current environment. This didn't happen in one case.

When are Windows environment variable changes applied? What am I missing? Is this an artifact of some weird installer for the 3rd party software? Is this an artifact of Windows being flaky?

To boil it all down to one question: **what happened**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes made using the `SET` command are NOT permanent, they apply to the current `CMD prompt` only and remain only until the `CMD` window is closed.
To permanently change a variable at the command line use `SetX`
or with the GUI - `Control Panel | System | Environment | System/User Variables`

cf. [SETX.exe (Resource Kit, Windows 7)](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

**Updated**: though we don't know the way *the 3rd party installer* changes the system path environment variable, all symptoms indicate doing it by registry change - and if does not broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message, then, according to Microsoft Technet and MSDN pages, changes do not take effect until you log off and then log back on - or even restart the computer... (through, or due to,  caching of some registry data).

The behavior described in your question does not seem to be  weird: it's not an error, it's a feature... :-)

Comment: I concur with you JosefZ. My usage of the `set` command was simply to inspect what environment variables were passed on to a new shell. I was not setting them from the command line, as the 3rd party installer set them for me.

Comment: Seems very likely it didn't broadcast WM_SETTINGCHANGE. Thanks.